# What is the recommended way of attaching JavaScript to a link

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's my sample code..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){ 
$("a.change").click(function(){  
$("a.change").hide();
$("div#change").append("<a href=''>Hello world!</a><a href=''>lounge</a>");
});
});
</script>
<div id="change">
<a href="javascript:;" class="change" name="change">Change Vote</a>
</div>
```

The code works great..but i read in various forums about using "href=javascript:;" as inconsistent and outdated! Is that true? If yes, then how do I overcome this obsoleteness?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the `href` to [a sensible server side fallback](http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/) for middle-clickers and non-JS users.

… and in this case, since "Change Vote" is [not idempotent, you should also use a POST form](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/methods.html) instead of a link.

Comment: +1 I middle click 90% of links, please don't get me pissed when I find an orphaned tab with the `javascript:` psuedo protocol and no idea where it came from :)

Comment: Because making a site work for more people means more potential customers and because you don't want [a minor JS error](http://www.webmonkey.com/2011/02/gawker-learns-the-hard-way-why-hash-bang-urls-are-evil/) to make a site completely inaccessible to everyone. Stop being dependent on jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Use `#!` instead of `javascript:;`

`#!` will also prevent browser to scroll top

Comment: That is just as useless as `javascript:`. Progressive enhancement is the way.